# Create custom jsdocs, java docs, php doc

Tags: java, php, phpstorm, webstorm

I usually use jetbrains family ide. It is very useful when create doc for a function , just simply type `/**`

How to create a custom tag when create docs, example @date tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a custom tag"? Maybe you wanted to say "**Add** custom tag into generated Doc comment"?

Comment: Yes sir. That is what I want

Comment: No clue about Java/IntelliJ. For JS docs/WebStorm -- they all hardcoded AFAIK (so you cannot add your own **automatically**). As for PHPDoc/PhpStorm -- it has a few templates which you can customize: `Settings | File and Code Templates` -- look at "Includes" and "Code" tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript, Java: stubs generation is hardcoded, and thus can't be customized. Related ticket: [IDEA-97658](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97658)
PHP: as @LazyOne has mentioned, you can edit doc comment templates in `Settings/File and Code templates/Includes`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Hope this feature will be supported soon